# ag-grid how can I disable spacebar keyevent

Tags: ag-grid, keyevent

ag-grid has a keyevent that's attached to spacebar (32) by default. This conflicts with other functionality of my app. I can't figure out to disable it.

I tried suppressHeaderKeyboardEvent but I'm not sure how to implement it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.